# Find the missing angle ABC triangle, knowing only angle BAC, side AB and the perimeter

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

This question is similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378105/find-the-other-side-lengths-of-a-triangle-given-the-perimeter-one-side-and-an-a), but in my case the actual numbers do not matter, I'm interested in the equations.

I have an arbitrary triangle, of which only angle BAC and side AB are known.
The sum of sides BC and AC (therefore the perimeter) is known and fixed.

I am looking for an equation that gives me the value of angle ABC.

Here's a screenshot, please remember that the exact dimensions are arbitrary, and are only there to show which parts are known.
[Triangle drawn in CAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBdPL.png)

This is really driving me crazy, I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical example of a problem which can be routinely solved using the $p,q$ method  i.e., we assume that $A,B,C$ are $(0,0)$, $(c,0)$ and $(p,q)$.  We can then find $p,q$ as functions of the three given quantities by solving $$ \frac qp =\tan A, c+((p-c)^2+q^2)^{1/2}+(p^2+q^2)^{1/2}=per.$$  This can be done by hand but I used Mathematica (the solution is not complicated but bad enough for it not to be feasible for me to type it in).

Once you know $p$ and $q$, you can easily find any triangle quantity, in particular $\angle ABC$.

Comment: Just played with your solution in Desmos, it works like a charm!
Can we express p and q as functions of A and Perimeter without each one involving the other?

Comment: Yes. This is an example of what I call the generalised Heron principle.  A kindergarten formulation: given any three triangle quantities, you can compute any further ones in terms of them.  The classical version uses the three side lengths and expresses the area.  The method is uniform--you compute the three expressions for the above triangle (with $C=(c,0)$ since one can't always rescale) and solve the resulting equations for $p,q ,c$ in terms of the given. quantities. You then recapture the area, say, as $\frac 12 qc$.  Of course, this only works if you can solve the equations explicitly.

Comment: However this can usually be done for the standard triangle quantities of elementary geometry, often by hand but especially if you are prepared to use Mathematica or your favourite system.  For example, the classical Heron formula can be obtained by hand in a few minutes (and you don't even have to know the result from the start--it falls out of the computation).

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With the great help of @user131781 and then [mathway.com](https://www.mathway.com/Algebra) (to solve for x) I managed to express the **x** coordinate of the missing corner of the triangle as a function of triangle perimeter P and angle A, **when |AB| is scaled to 1**. The definition of y is trivial:

$$x=\frac{P\cdot (2−P)}{2\cdot (sec(A)−P\cdot sec(A)+1)}$$

$$y=x \cdot  tan(A)$$

Reminder that the secant function is defined as$$sec(x)= \frac {1}{cos(x)}$$
(most computer languages/libraries don't have a built-in secant function).

The above formulation makes it trivial to calculate the third point of the triangle using any programming language. Once the third point is found, calculating the remaining sides and angles is trivial!

I plotted the 3 equations (2 from the correct answer, and the simplified x solution from mathway.com) in Desmos, and it's a thing of beauty!
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ghs0nxhhli

*Note: The generic formulation with |AB| being variable (instead of normalized to 1) crashed every online solver I tried. Any help for a truly general solution would be appreciated!*